# Firestore orderBy timestamp desc not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore in one of my project. Query working perfectly here but when Im try to ordering the query by timestamp desc, its not working

Here is my code

```
let ref = db.collection('customers').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')

  ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
      if(change.type == 'added'){
        let doc = change.doc
        this.customers.push({
          id:doc.id,
          customer_name:doc.data().customer_name,             
          designation:doc.data().designation,
          timestamp:moment(doc.data().timestamp).fromNow('lll')
        })
      }
    })
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: In my code you can see the query I run to retrieve value from customers collections. well value shows perfectly but by default the value shows acrobatically order. but I want to show the result according the timestamp.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this. Your question is not very clear but I think I have a similar problem